# Java writeBytes white space replaced by '+'

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot

when trying to do a post request using HttpURLConnection, white spaces in the message got replaced by '+' and '=' is added at the end of the String.
I am using JDK 1.8.0_91, here is my code :

```
public void sendPost(String message) throws Exception {
String url = "http://localhost:8081/subscribe";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        /*String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";*/

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(message);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
}
```

sendPost("Say Hi") would give on server side : Say+Hi=

Comment: Unrelated, but *why* are you using `DataOutputStream`?

Comment: Where are you seeing "Say+Hi="? Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i am logging the received messages from client in a spingBoot application's log file. after step by step debug issue is from  wr.writeBytes(message);

Comment: `DataOutputStream.writeBytes()` definitely does not do this, as you could have easily established for yourself by writing to something else with it, or reading the Javadoc. The problem could be with `HttpURLConnection`, although unlikely, but most likely it is at the receiving end. You need to debug further.

Comment: Here is the the receiving end, all what is does is logging :

`code`@RequestMapping(value = "/subscribe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String createNewUser(@RequestBody String message) {
        log.info(message);}

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` doesn't do it either. I checked. You could and should have done that yourself before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't set the `Content-Type` request header (using `setRequestProperty()`), it defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

When a POST request has content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the `ServletRequest.getParameter` methods can be used to extract the parameters from the request body. This *consumes* the request body, so any subsequent call to `getInputStream()` or `getReader()` will return null.

When your Spring handler method asks for the request body with the `@RequestBody` annotation, and the body has already been consumed, Spring will rebuild the body from the parameters, in order to supply the method parameter (it is basically faking it). When Spring rebuilds the request body from the parsed parameters, it will URL encode them as required by the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. This encoding converts spaces to `+`.

The original request body with `Say Hi` was parsed as parameter `"Say Hi"` with value `""` (parameter without `=` has empty value). When that is rebuilt in compliance with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the parameter is encoded as `Say+Hi=`, which is what you're seeing.

This only happens if one of the `ServletRequest.getParameter` methods has been called, so you likely have a `Filter` that does that. If that filter was removed, the request body wouldn't have been consumed, and the `@RequestBody` parameter would have received the original request body.

Another way to prevent the problem is to send the request body as a `text/plain` content type, since that seems to be how you want it anyway, i.e. the request body is not actually `x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

Of course, if the request body truly *is* `x-www-form-urlencoded` content, like your commented code would suggest, then there shouldn't *be* any spaces, and there was no problem to begin with.

**To recap:** Your problem is that you're sending arbitrary text in the POST body, but you didn't set the content type, so it defaulted to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and your content doesn't conform to the specifications of that content type, i.e. your request is malformed and behaved unpredictably.

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` does not do this encoding, and neither (obviously) does `DataOutputStream.writeBytes()`. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @EJP You're right, `HttpURLConnection` is not adding the `+`, but it *is* defaulting content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which means that the Servlet Container or the Spring Framework reads the content and parses it as parameters, and when you then ask for the content with `@RequestBody` (like OP does), it rebuilds them, with the side-effect of encoding spaces as `+`. The Servlet Container/Spring Framework wouldn't do that if the content type was something else, so I believe that setting the content type is still the solution to the problem.

Comment: You have it back to front. The Servlet container will *decode* + as spaces. There's no reason for the server side to encode.

Comment: @EJP My point was that the POST payload was *consumed* when the "form fields" were processed as parameters, so when the method requests the full payload with the `@RequestBody` annotations, it has to be *rebuild* from the parameters. The rebuilding doesn't know that the original payload was incorrectly encoded, so it encodes it the way it was supposed to be encoded.

Comment: @Andreas you were right, i set the content type to text/plain and it worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing with the same situation. I have this little code block in backend and I am trying to send a string like 'Ekin Frontend' and it converts is 'Ekin+Frontend=' at the backend.

Here is my code block;

```
@PostMapping("/error")
public boolean addError( @RequestBody String errorMsg) {
    ...
}
```